# How to setup OWASP plugin to sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, owasp

I am trying to find a documentation on how to setup OWASP project https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_SonarQube_Project to setup it for SonarQube. I tried to find in available plugins but i couldn't find anything related to it. I read few documentation and little bit confused how to use OWASP to SonarQube.
I have SonarQube 5.6 version. Can anyone help me to understand how to setup OWASP in SonarQube.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

There is no plugins to add. All the rules of your langage you have in SonarQube are tagged "cwe, owasp, bug" or something like this.

You could setup a profile with all the rules you want to check and name it "OWASP profile".

BTW, actually the OWASP SonarQube project was closed. And nothing more will be done on it.